# Torndb - Switch from one database to another

Tags: python, tornado

I am connecting to MySQL database using torndb in Python. Is there a way to switch between databases after connection is established? Like the `select_db` method?

Answer (score 2):

Switch db:

> conn.execute('use anotherDBName');

Answer (score 0):

this ultimately will be decided if the database is running on the same host and in the instance of MySQL.  If it is running in the same instance you should be able to prefix your tables names with the database name. For example; "select splat from foo.bar where splat is not null"  where foo is the database name and bar is the table name.  Hope this helps!